# Gx X Ev3, Desenvolvimento Genexus Java Environment

Tags: java, genexus

> Nota: Em Genexus, que é um "criador" de pacotes de código para desenvolvimento ágil, não se necessita codificar em linguagem comum como o Java. Apenas criando a transação especificando os seus atributos já é o suficiente para que se crie o "objeto" e até com uma pré-interface com um CRUD básico.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Genexus e utilizando Java/MySQL como Environment. Criei apenas uma transação como teste. Está tudo ok, mas ao mandar executar o programa e a geração do Build e Developer Menu nada acontece, nem sequer uma janela aparece.

O que pode ser?

Estou programando para Java Win/Web.

Comment: Fica complicado te ajudar se você não nos ajudar a entender qual é o problema. Por que não [edita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/56680/edit) a pergunta fornecendo mais informações e trechos de código? Bem vindo ao StackOverflow.

Comment: @renan Aparentemente ele não escreveu nenhum código. Uma "transação" complexa pode ser feita em Genexus sem escrever nenhuma linha de código.

Comment: Exatamente @Caffé]

Comment: Em Genexus, que é um "criador" de pacotes de código para desenvolvimento ágil, não se necessita codificar em linguagem comum como o Java. Apenas criando a transação especificando os seus atributos já é o suficiente para que se crie o "objeto" e até com uma pré-interface com um CRUD básico.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você tem a janela de Output fechada e mensagens de saída (erro) estão lá. Você pode abrir a janela com a opção View/Other Tool windows/Output.

Comment: Não estou com a janela de Output fechada. Foi uma das primeiras coisas que eu fui verificar. Como eu disse no tópico. Está tudo "certo", mas não tenho qualquer resposta. Fui até atrás de atualizar todos os arquivos para ver se foi falta de algum complemento, mas nada. Não sei mais o que fazer.